# Modern operating system / compiler where int (in C) is not 32 bits?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

The question is actually somewhat broader.

Based on the last 15 years experience I currently assume that size of types is as follows:

```
byte = 8 bit

short = 2 bytes

int = 4 bytes

long long = 8 bytes
```

Is there a modern OS where this assumption can be challenged?

Comment: It's not so much about the OS or compiler, it's about the underlying hardware.

Comment: If you count embedded systems there are several (PIC, AVR, etc).

Comment: All kinds of embedded systems.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models), Solaris for SPARC64 and Unicos both use 8-byte `int`. In fact, on Unicos, short is also 8 bytes!

Comment: Some compilers support the ILP64 model: meaning that ints, longs and pointers are 64 bits.

Comment: This question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc

Comment: Yes, looks similar, though I would not ask about sizeof(long) ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth it is absolutely about compiler.  Size of pointer depends on the architecture, size of int doesn't.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Unicos on the T90 has 64-bit `short`; Unicos on the T3E (Alpha processor) has 32-bit `short`.

Comment: @MK: Whilst size of integer is up to the compiler, it's overwhelmingly chosen to match the native word size of the ALU, etc.  A similar argument holds for pointers.

Comment: Making `int` 64 bits and `char` 8 bits means that you can't have predefined types for both 16 and 32 bits; `short` can be one or the other, but not both.  C99 introduced extended integer types, but I don't know of any compilers that actually provide them.  That's probably why 64-bit `int` is still uncommon even on 64-bit systems.

Comment: @KeithThompson: you mean `stdint.h`? What about glibc?

Comment: @ninjalj: No, C99 introduced the concept of *extended integer types*, whose names ight be compiler-defined keywords like `__uint128`.  The typedefs in `<stdint.h>` might be defined either as normal types like `long long`, or as extended types.  I don't know what glibc would have to do with it.

Comment: `long long` is usually *16-bytes* on 64-bit unices along with 8-byte `long`, while 32-bit unices and both 32 and 64-bit windows have 4-byte `long` and 8-byte `long long`. The assumption about `long long` is not widely applicable.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The `__int??` and `__uint??` types were taken from Microsoft compiler, which had them for ages (though IIRC it still does not have all of C99, because Microsoft only focuses on C++). Gcc does not, because the standard types always covered all that was needed so far (well, when it didn't, gcc invented the `long long`).

Comment: @Jan Hudec - I claim tat there is no Unix with 16 byte or 128 bit "long long". Prove me wrong and tell where you have seen it;)

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub: Hm, you are right. I've seen somewhere that it should generally be 128-bit, but it isn't.

Comment: @Jan Hudec, perhaps, what you've seen was about "long double". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double mentions 128-bit couple of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not such "[modern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman)" systems exist, you should `static_assert` assert those assumptions in your code so that if your code is ever ported to a platform where the assumption is incorrect, the person doing the porting will be alerted to the problem immediately.

Comment: It might be good to explain `static_assert` (which is not a standard language feature, at least not yet).

Comment: @pmr I believe C201x (work in progress) intoduces a static assert feature. There are ways to emulate it in C90 and C99.

Answer (score 3):

The standard is intentionally vague on this subject, only specifying:

- C90: `sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)`
- C99: `sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`

Furthermore, C99 only requires that int be at least a 16-bit value.

Also, 'byte' is not a C datatype.

Comment: Shouldn't be `<= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`?

Comment: I know standard is vague, my question was more from practical point of view.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub: If you want a practical answer I would use the types defined in the `stdint.h` header.

Comment: @Michas: Yes, it's definitely `<=` (I've edited the answer accordingly).  But the relationships are actually stated in terms of *ranges*, not sizes (the requirement for binary representations implies minimum sizes, but not all bits necessarily contribute to the value).  The range of each type in the following list is a subset of the range of the following type: `signed char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` (the latter was introduced in C99).  The minimum sizes in bits are: `char`: 8, `short`: 16, `int`: 16, `long`: 32, `long long` 64 (again, actually defined in terms of ranges).

Comment: It's true that `byte` is not a C datatype, but the C standard does use the word to refer to an "addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment".  Other than on some embedded systems, a C byte is almost always 8 bits (it must always be at least 8 bits).  `unsigned char` is effectively a byte type (`char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are all one byte in size, by definition.)

Comment: @Blastfurnace, you're expecting too modern environment:) I do also work with environments where stdint.h does not exist

Comment: -1 for a completely non-useful answer -- the question is specifically asking about what actual implementations do, not what the standard guarentees

Comment: @Chris: My point is: do not assume that majority rules here.  Just because many environments treat the same type names the same in terms of size, it is dangerous to believe that is a de-facto rule.

Comment: @Joe, the question wasn't about the majority, the question was about exceptions to the majority. This answer contains some good background information, but it doesn't answer the question - at all.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models) [Unicos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicos) has int as 64bit.  Of course the definition of a "modern" compiler is pretty vague.  You can still buy Borland C++ for MS DOS and have your ints are 16bit, but is that modern?

Comment: Has anyone actually seen/worked with Unicos? Everybody points to the same Wikipedia article:) Is Unicos as rare as say, a unicorn?

Comment: @Vladislav - If your assumption has been true for the last 15 years, what about the next 15 years? I have been doing this for 30 years and moved from 8 bits to 64 bits in that time.

Comment: @Bo, my theory is that further increase in bitness less likely to occur at the same pace, once 64 bit has been reached. But nevermind that I believe that next-gen 128 bit integer won't be char,short,int,long or long long.  It will be int128_t or long long long or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty much platforms (especially in embedded) where it is not. You e.g. can have 2-octet char.

Comment: -1 `char` is guaranteed to be one byte in size (yes, you can have bytes that are 16 bits wide, but it's still one byte).

Comment: pedantic check detected. I should use term "2-octet char" to be exact.

Comment: `short` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits.

Comment: Yes Keith, you're right, now I've read through C99 #5.2.4.2.1 more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably one exception.

```
long long = error
```

I've heard there are problems with old Microsoft C compilers. I've seen some workarounds in source code. However Microsoft 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16 (from Visual Studio 2010) do have long long.

Comment: 'long long' is in Microsoft Visual C++ compiler since at least 2003:)

Comment: [Product Changes: Visual C++ .NET 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7223w6b0(VS.80).aspx) says : "The long long type is now available as a typedef of __int64."

Comment: Well. I'll try to find Microsoft C compiler and test it.